# How to add content to a block?

Tags: 8, blocks

[image]I have created a few blocks via `/block/add` and assigned these blocks to various regions defined in my theme.

How am I able to add content to these blocks?

Comment: You need to clarify your question: how did you create your blocks? Have you tried to create block instances via `/admin/structure/block`?

Comment: @Gun5m0k3, Yes, I've created block instances.  But I'd like to add content to these blocks.  I've updated my post with a screenshot of my `/admin/structure/block` view

Comment: And how did you create these blocks, via the UI (`/block/add`) or programmatically?

Comment: @Gun5m0k3, only the ISI block was created via `/block/add` and the rest already existed in a fresh installation of Drupal.  I did however delete some of the existing blocks.

Comment: @Gun5m0k3, I should mention that I'm totally new to the Drupal `/admin` interface, however I'm very familiar with WordPress.  Do blocks belong to a page or some other content type?  The main reason I am at this point is because I'm creating a theme with specific regions that won't render unless I have content within a block assigned to that region.

Comment: Then go to `/admin/structure/block/block-content` and click on `Edit`. You should see a body text area. There you can enter your content.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61513/discussion-between-gun5m0k3-and-raphael-rafatpanah).

Comment: Ahh.  Nice.  So is it correct to say that a block is piece of content that does not belong to, for example, a page?  I'm now trying to figure out how to get the region to render properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If blocks are added via `/block/add` you can edit the block content via `/admin/structure/block/block-content`. Click on `Edit` and you should see a body text area appear. You can enter your block content there.